# Excluding DJStripe Logs in Django

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

Im trying to exclude the djstripe logs from my django and prevent them being printed to the console.

I have this config in my `settings.py` but when i perform Stripe operations I still see them on the console.

```
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "handlers": {
        "file": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "filename": BASE_DIR / "web_debug.log",
        },
        "console": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
        },
        "djstripe_file": {  # File handler specifically for djstripe
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "filename": BASE_DIR / "djstripe.log",
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "djstripe": {  # Logger specifically for djstripe
            "handlers": ["djstripe_file"],  # Using the djstripe_file handler
            "level": "WARNING",
            "propagate": False,
        },
    },
    "root": {  # Correctly defining the root logger outside the "loggers" dictionary
        "handlers": ["console"],
        "level": "INFO",
    },
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

remove this part :

> "console": {
> "level": "INFO",
> "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
> },

from your "handlers" and try it again.